# Array index out of bound when i am click on view button

Tags: android

This is code i have use for android app.Here are array index out of bound problem coming.After that app is crash.can anyone help to me.

```
private void displayAvailableProjects() {
    projectList = databaseHelper.getAllProjects();
    if (projectList.size() >= 0) {   //here chnages =
        projectViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ArrayList<String> projects = new ArrayList<>();
        projects.add("Previous Report");
        for (ProjectEntity project : projectList) {
            projects.add(project.getProjectName());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> projectListAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(Projectinfo.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, projects);
        spinnerProject.setAdapter(projectListAdapter);
        spinnerProject.setSelected(false);
    } else {
        projectViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
if (spinnerProject.getSelectedItemPosition() !=0)
                   openProjectFeedbackActivity(projectList.get(spinnerProject.getSelectedItemPosition()).getProjectId());
```

Comment: Place your code in `try`- `catch` block

Comment: Show your complete code and specify your logs if possible.

Comment: if(projectList.size()>0).... change to this line... remove =

Answer (score 0):

```
if (projectList.size() >= 0)
```

This line is the problem.
 Your projectList size is 0 and yet you are displaying the list

change it to

```
 if (projectList.size() > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
private void displayAvailableProjects() {
try{
    projectList = databaseHelper.getAllProjects();

    if (projectList.size() > 0) {   //here chnages =
        projectViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ArrayList<String> projects = new ArrayList<>();
        projects.add("Previous Report");
        for (ProjectEntity project : projectList) {
           projects.add(project.getProjectName());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> projectListAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(Projectinfo.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, projects);
        spinnerProject.setAdapter(projectListAdapter);
        spinnerProject.setSelected(false);
    } else {
    projectViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
 }catch(Exception e){
  e.printstack();
 }
} 
if (spinnerProject.getSelectedItemPosition() !=0)openProjectFeedbackActivity(projectList.get(spinnerProject.getSelectedItemPosition()).getProjectId());
```

Comment: Unfrotunately Application has been stop

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
com.agreindia.passionchecklist.Projectinfo.onClick(Projectinfo.java:245)
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)